# Add element of list, return in form of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add the element of list together which is given in the data-frame and return in same shape of data-frame.
As shown in data-frame below Ex: at position (0,0) data is [1,1] output want (1+1) = 2 at (0,0).
Similarly for all 5*5 data.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could unravel the dataframe's cell values into a one-dimensional NumPy array, so that you can use a list comprehension to take the sum over each value. The resulting list can be reshaped into a NumPy array with the same shape as the original dataframe and then be passed to the dataframe constructor function:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(np.array([sum(x) for x in df.values.ravel()]).reshape(df.shape))
```

Assuming that `df` is the name of the original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful